# How can I sort my arraylist named "serviceNeedingTasks" based on two attributes of an object

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

Does anyone know how can I sort  "serviceNeedingTasks"  based on multiplication of two attributes of  "Tasks" that are "p_t" and " weight"? It seems it doesnt work correct because it sort just based on "p_t".

```
Collections.sort(serviceNeedingTasks, new Comparator<Tasks>() {
          public int compare(Tasks c1, Tasks c2) {
            if (c1.p_t)*(c1.weight) > (c2.p_t)*(c1.weight) return -1;
            if (c1.p_t)*(c1.weight) < (c2.p_t)*(c1.weight) return 1;
            return 0;
          }});
```

Comment: You are not using c2.weight in your condition update your condition as (c1.p_t)*(c1.weight) > (c2.p_t)*(c2.weight)

Comment: You are not using c2's weight property in the second operand of your comparison.